# Best practices for PHP ini settings for large wordpress site?

Tags: linux, php, best-practices

I own a large wordpress site that gets

- 500k+ visitors
- 30+ plugins (some heavy)
- server with 128 GB RAM

Wondering if there are "best practices" for php.ini settings for larger sites on Linux? I think my host may be cutting corners to save bandwidth, but I'm not 100% sure where to start on php ini settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to [Can you help me with my capacity planning](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning). The same principles apply as in the linked question's answer.

For your case, more important than `php.ini` settings is the setup details. Do you have proper caching enabled? Does the database server have enough memory?

Comment: Not sure, host handles all that.

Comment: Host does not handle anything related to WordPress and its caching. You should look into WordPress cache modules first.